# Reverse for 'order_page' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: django, request, render

i am trying to write a Django project in which i pass data ('cart') from detail.html in the app called 'cart' to another app ('order') and display it in its template. However i get the next error :

> Reverse for 'order_page' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried: ['order\/order_page\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']
>   The parts related to this task of my project are :

detail.html

```
{% with totail_items=cart|length %}
    {% if cart|length > 0 %}
        My Shopping Order:
.................
{% for item in cart %}
    {% with product=item.product  %}
        {{ product.name }}
        <form action="{% url "cart:cart_add" product.id %}" method="post">
.............
<a href="{% url 'order:order_page' request.cart.id %}"> ORDER </a>
```

cart/views.py

```
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'update': True})
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

order/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('order_page/<int:cart>/', views.OrderPage, name='order_page'),   
    ]
```

order/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def OrderPage(request):
    return render(request,'order/orderr.html', {'cart.id':cart.id})
```

Can you please help me? 
Ideally i want the data i pass from detail.html to be displayed in orderr.html

Comment: A `request` has no `cart`, so `request.cart.id` will not work.

Comment: Hello, i tried erasing 'request' it still doesnt work

Comment: please stay away from "voodoo programming". What do you pass as context to the page you are rendering?

Comment: My bad, i just edited it

Comment: Could you show full traceback? Because seem like the error not comes from your template. Btw, if you want to use `order:order_page`, you should add `app_name = "order"` on top of your `urls.py` file, right above `urlpatterns`

Comment: It is added, i just didnt show it. Sure, but what do you mean by full traceback?